# Memorize react change handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, state

I know that react component will render everytime state changes and useCallBack memorize function depending on the dependency array provided.

But If I have this:

```js
<input type="text" name="name" value={values.name} onChange={handleChange} />
<input type="text" name="phone" value={values.phone} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Whats the difference between these two handleChange implementation?

```js
const handleChange = e => {
  setValues(values => ({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
}
```

and

```js
const handleChange = useCallback(e => {
  setValues(values => ({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))
}), [])
```

**Code snippet needed in comment**

```js
const Child = () => {
  console.log("Child rerendered");
  return <div>Hello World </div>;
};
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log("Parent rerendered");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount((x) => x + 1);
        }}
      >
        {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In short `handleChange` without `useCallback` will have an unstable identity, whereas `handleChange` with `useCallback` and an empty dependency array has a stable identity.

Comment: How about passing anonymous function to another component?
Would it be re-created in every new render??

Comment: Yes. Passing an asynchronous function would still create and pass a new instance of the function for each new render. It is essentially the same as `handleChange` without `useCallback`—with the only difference that it doesn't have a label/name.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with the second one using `useCallback`, you'll keep using the first `handleChange` function you create; with the first one where you don't use `useCallback`, you're creating a new handler function each time. (Technically, you *create* a new one every time in both cases, but `useCallback` will only return the first one that gets created, because you've provided an empty dependency array.) More in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

It doesn't matter much when giving the handler function to `input` or other native HTML elements, or even simple components. If you were providing this handler function to a complex component, it might be better to use `useCallback` if that complex component optimizes re-rendering (for instance, with `React.memo`, `PureComponent`, or `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Comment: How about passing anonymous function to another component?
Would it be re-created in every new render??

Comment: @Jomanog - Whether the function has a name doesn't matter. But if you mean an inline function expression like `onClick={e => { /*...*/ }}` then yes, that's a new function every time that expression is evaluated (which is every time the component function is called -- e.g., every render).

Comment: Sorry but how would that prevent rerendering childrens that utilize handleChange?
I mean, When a component rerenders , all of his children willl be already rerendered.

Comment: So, Memorizing the function wouldn't do any better , right?

Comment: @Jomanog - I suggest reading up on `React.memo`, `PureComponent`, and `shouldComponentUpdate`. Basically: No, all of a component's child components don't have to be re-rendered when it is re-rendered; the previous rendering can be reused, but only if the props haven't changed in a way the child component will care about. Giving it a different change handler is definitely something the child component will care about, thus causing re-rendering.

Comment: **Please check the snippet in the below comment**
But in this example.  everytime you click the button, it will print "child rerendered" as well !?

Comment: @Jomanog - Again, please read up on the memoization stuff. The thing you'd use in that code would be `React.memo`.